# how to display a class according to the state of the object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, frontend, ng-class

I am developing a quiz software where i wanted to show a pointers of numbers for each questions. I have doubt in how to display different class for the pointers at a different state of the questions and a sequence of numbers on top of it.

i have coded for two senarios

```
ng-class="{

    'ibps-answered': question.selected !== null,
    'ibps-not-answered': question.selected === null

    }",

    ng-click="quiz.setActiveQuestion($index)"">1
```

the Four different states of the questions are as follow

```
`class="ibps-not-visited"`:questions at initial stage without touching "`default`"

`class="ibps-not-answered"`:questions visited but options are not attempted

`class="ibps-review"`:"have a special button for marking it for review in future without answering it." 



class="ibps-answered":"Have attempted the questions"

class="ibps-review-answered":"have attempted and also marked for review"
```

First condition is going to be a default case. How can i achieve the other four conditions. Please give me some suggestions.

Comment: share your complete code!!

Comment: iam expecting a logic arvind, iam not aware of what happens to that object when these event happens.. Moreover these are all common conditional situations of a form

Answer (score 0):

I would create a function to return the class

```
ng-class={{getClass()}}

$scope.getClass = function(){
  //logic here
  return className;
}
```

You could of course add inputs to the function to expand the logic

Comment: I need to put everything in ng-repeat..... if 100 questions available the i cant do this i guess.. More over i want a logic in which it satisfy that condition.

Comment: @NivasDhina I modified the answer to be more in line with what you need

Answer (score 0):

Use nested inline if-then statements:

```
<div ng-class=" ... ? 'class-1' : ( ... ? 'class-2' : 'class-3')">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function in your controller to control and check the states of each question then use ng-class to apply each class or not:

```
<li ng-class="{ 'ibps-answered':yourCtrl.isAnswered('Question1'),  'ibps-not-visited':yourCtrl.isNotVisited('Question1'), ....}">
```

If you number out your questions use it as identifier in your function parameter

It Works with ng-repeat if the identifier is in your question's data